# How to Create a 2D vector with both keys as Integers

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have a c++ program currently working with a vector that uses a character and number as its keys. e.g. `myvector['A'][1] = line.substr(0,7)`. But I need it to work as `myvector[1][3] = line.substr(0,7)` so I can use both keys as numbers.

In my current working code I had this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >myvector;
```

I thought simply changing the string to integer would work but I get a "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" or "cannot convert ‘std::basic_string’ to ‘int’ in assignment" error.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >myvector;
```

I know that error is very vague but I am new to c++ so I do not how to find any other specific command response for an error. I have looked around on the web for a bunch of examples but have sadly not been able to compile any of them. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated; thank you for your time.

If I am somehow using indexes out of my range here is how I am inputting my indexes.

```
myvector[rn].resize(100);
std::ifstream fin(argv[3]);
std::string line;
int rn = 0;
int rln = 0;
while( getline(fin, line) ) {  
rn = 0;
while(rn < line.length()/7){
  myvector[rn][rln] = line.substr (rn*7,7);
  rn++;
}
rln++;
}
```

When I output "line.substr (rn*7,7)" the results are exactly as expected I just cannot set this variable into my vector. Also rn ends up being around 10+ and rln ends at 6.

Comment: `I thought simply changing the string to integer would work but I get a "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" or "cannot convert ‘std::basic_string’ to ‘int’ in assignment" error.` Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, string is in double quote `"test"` not in single code `'test'`, try:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >myvector(3);
myvector[1].resize(10);
myvector[1][3] = "test";
std::cout << myvector[1][3] << std::endl;
```

Also With std::vector you have no key concept, actually you are calling access `operator[]`.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying enough; the value put into the vectors would be a sub-string. I just used single quotes by accident when making a simpler example for the question. Also I have only been working with C++ for a week; and PHP for years so the only relevant term I could think of was array keys because I didn't know the specific term in c++ vectors.

Comment: So I tried your number example and I get that Segmentation Error on run(At least I can compile). I assume this means I am trying to set or output a index combination that is not available? I will update my code above about how I input the variables.

Comment: did you call 'resize' first before you assign value to it? otherwise you are accessing vector element which is out of boundary

Comment: Yes I added the resize like you said before I assigned any values but still got the segmentation fault error. Also when I changed rn and rln to 0 0 it worked so I assume I just have to somehow make sure my range of rn and rln spots are created before I try to assign.

Comment: Well I tried adding above the loop after the vector is initialized and I also tried adding 'myvector[rn].resize(100);' on the first line in my second loop (see above).

Comment: Alright after some tinkering I figured out that I was trying to set for indexes that I have not created yet. And it was not a index problem like I thought. I got things roughly working now so I think after some more adjusting everything should work out fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change anything, vector is not an associative container, it can access its data only through index, which is what is already happening in your code since chars are automatically upcasted to ints when needed: when you do `data['A']`, A is treated as its int value in ASCII encoding.

In any case, if your values are sparse, consider using an associative continer like `map<vector<string> >`.